# Understanding the notion of "indifferent health"

Tags: word-meaning

American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fourth Edition, provides these definitions for the word "indifferent":

> adj. Having no particular interest or concern; apathetic: indifferent to the sufferings of others.
>
> adj. Having no marked feeling for or against: She remained indifferent toward their proposal.
>
> adj. Not mattering one way or the other: It's indifferent to me which outfit you choose.
>
> adj. Characterized by a lack of partiality; unbiased: an indifferent judge.
>
> adj. Being neither too much nor too little; moderate.
>
> adj. Being neither good nor bad; mediocre: an indifferent performance. See Synonyms at average.
>
> adj. Being neither right nor wrong.
>
> adj. Not active or involved; neutral: an indifferent chemical in a reaction.

After having read the above definitions I was unable to understand the notion/concept/meaning of "indifferent health" to which Cardinal Keith O’Brien refers in this statement:

> Approaching the age of 75 and at times in **indifferent health**, I tendered my resignation as Archbishop of St Andrews and Edinburgh to Pope Benedict XVI some months ago. ([LINK](http://www.catholicherald.co.uk/news/2013/02/25/pope-accepts-resignation-of-cardinal-keith-obrien/))

Can anybody explain?

Answer (score 9):

The literal meaning is your “Being neither good nor bad; mediocre”; but *indifferent health* is really a long-established fixed phrase which is understood as a *meiosis* (deliberate understatement) for “poor health”.

For instance, Charles Booth's [*The Aged Poor in England and Wales*](http://books.google.com/books?id=uX0EAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA356&dq=%22indifferent+health%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xq0rUaiGFYKVygGhkIDoAg&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22indifferent%20health%22&f=false) (1894) categorizes paupers as being in “Good”, “Fair”, “Indifferent” and “Bad” health. “Indifferent” here is, to be sure, “neither good nor bad”; but it falls into the inferior part of that mediocrity.